# woocommerce show cities state as dropdown list

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

im trying to show a list of cities when the user selects a state on woocommerce, some one have some luck doing this??

I find this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
     unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_city']);
     return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['billing_ciudad']= array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'label'     => __('Ciudad', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('San Salvador', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true,
     );


     $fields['billing']['billing_ciudad']['options'] = array(
        'option_1' => 'Col. Escalon',
        'option_2' => 'Otro ciudad o colonia'
        );


     return $fields;
}
```

Im trying to only show this field when a state is selected and show specific cities for each state.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved something similar using the `woocommerce_default_address_fields` filter

You can do something in the lines of this to create your new cities:

```
// UPDATE CHECKOUT CITY FIELD
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $address_fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {

    // Billing City
    $address_fields['city']['type'] = 'select';
    $address_fields['city']['label'] = 'Suburb';

    $address_fields['city']['options'] = array(
        '' => '',
        'bo_kaap' => 'Bo-Kaap',
        'devils_peak_estate' => 'Devil\'s Peak Estate',
        'de_waterkant' => 'De Waterkant',
        'foreshore' => 'Foreshore'
    );

    // Sort
    ksort($address_fields['city']['options']);

    // to be added last and not sorted
    $address_fields['city']['options']['other'] = 'Other';

    return $address_fields;
}
```

Then using javascript to detect when your state is selected, and reveal the cities dropdown that you just created. I hope this is what you were looking for, thought I would share